# How are SELECT queries isolated from each other with MariaDB 10.1?

Tags: innodb, mariadb, isolation-level, mariadb-10.1

Given the following tables..

```sql
CREATE TABLE `event` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `data` longblob NOT NULL,
  `acknowledged` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
  `delivery_failed` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `acknowledged_delivery_failed_type` (`acknowledged`,`delivery_failed`,`type`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;

CREATE TABLE `delayed_event` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `data` longblob NOT NULL,
  `delivery_time` datetime NOT NULL,
  `last_value_key` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `acknowledged` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `delivery_failed` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `type_last_value_key` (`type`,`last_value_key`),
  KEY `acknowledged_delivery_failed_type_delivery_time` (`acknowledged`,`delivery_failed`,`type`,`delivery_time`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;
```

..and connection 1 and 2 concurrently doing (with `autocommit=1`)..

```sql
INSERT INTO event (type, data) VALUES ('foo', 1234);
```

```sql
INSERT INTO event (type, data) VALUES ('foo', 5678);
```

..resulting in the event with data `1234` getting ID 101, and `5678` getting ID 102.

Is there any chance that the following query run at about the same time on either connection 2 or on a 3rd connection will return the event with ID 102? If yes, why would that be, and is there anything that can be done about it?

```sql
(
  SELECT id, type, data, 1 AS delayed
  FROM delayed_event
  WHERE acknowledged = 0 AND delivery_failed = 0
    AND type = 'foo' AND delivery_time <= UTC_TIMESTAMP()
  ORDER BY id
  LIMIT 1
)
UNION
(
  SELECT id, type, data, 0 AS delayed
  FROM event
  WHERE acknowledged = 0 AND delivery_failed = 0
    AND type = 'foo' AND id > 100
  ORDER BY id
  LIMIT 1
)
ORDER BY id
LIMIT 1
```

I am unable to reproduce this in my own environment, but I believe this has happened in production. Using Ubuntu 18.04 and the MariaDB 10.1 package it provides. Reading about [isolation levels](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/set-transaction/#isolation-level) and [auto increment handling for InnoDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/auto_increment-handling-in-innodb/), I can't find any reason why this would happen.

Comment: Could there be a "102" in `delayed_event`?

Comment: In this case, it doesn't matter, because the application knows the difference. I realize I left out one critical part in that regard, the first subquery has an additonal constant 1 in the SELECT, and the second subquery sets the same field to 0. `SELECT id, type, data, 1 AS delayed_event ...`.

Comment: Add three `ORDER BYs` so that it can be deterministic, then I will look at it again.

Comment: Ok, added `ORDER BY` in the first subquery and for the `UNION`.

Comment: It is unlikely, _but possible_, for "102" to `COMMIT` before "101".

Comment: _Unlikely_ tend to turn into _likely_ in production. ;) In the end, I managed to reproduce it locally with the right set of setup and running tests long enough. I'd be happy to accept an answer if you want to turn your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 0):

From a general point of view:

```
 (
     SELECT id, type, data
     FROM delayed_event
     WHERE acknowledged = 0 AND delivery_failed = 0 AND type = 'foo' AND delivery_time <= UTC_TIMESTAMP()
     LIMIT 1
 )
```

is a SET (i.e. unordered). Any row that matches the predicates may be returned from this query. Let's call this row R1

In the same way:

```
(
    SELECT id, type, data
    FROM event
    WHERE acknowledged = 0 AND delivery_failed = 0 AND type = 'foo' AND id > 100
    ORDER BY id
    LIMIT 1
)
```

is a set, but you have an ORDER BY id. So the resulting row will be the row that satisfies the predicates, with the smallest if. Let's call this row R2

In your outer query, you construct the union of R1 and R2 and then pick any one of them.

If you prefer one leg over the other (I'll use the first one here) in the union, you can add an origin attribute like:

```
(
    SELECT id, type, data, 1 as origin
    FROM delayed_event
    WHERE acknowledged = 0 AND delivery_failed = 0 AND type = 'foo' AND delivery_time <= UTC_TIMESTAMP()
    LIMIT 1
)
UNION
(
    SELECT id, type, data, 2 as origin
    FROM event
    WHERE acknowledged = 0 AND delivery_failed = 0 AND type = 'foo' AND id > 100
    ORDER BY id
    LIMIT 1
)
ORDER BY origin
LIMIT 1
```

Note that the two legs now are disjoint so union will never remove duplicates (which is a semantic difference, don't know if that matters)

I would also advise you to add an "order by" to your first query for it to become deterministic.

If you don't want the origin to be part of the result, you can select the other columns at the outermost level.

Comment: Thanks for the insights, but I'm not sure if this answers the question. For the sake of the question, assume that the `delayed_event` table is always empty. I just included it to make sure that the example reflects reality as much as possible.

Comment: I see. Here is one possible explanation, don't know if it holds for MariaDB though. Even though you are using auto commit there might still be a chance that 102 is committed before 101 in a race condition. 101_INSERT, 102_INSERT, 102_COMMIT, 101_COMMIT

Comment: Interesting, so I think that's the million dollar question then, does that hold for MariaDB (10.1)? Eagerly awaiting someone with deep MariaDB expertise :)

Comment: I stumbled upon https://stackoverflow.com/a/14758690/1283519, which seems to say something along the same line. But I'd like to also have some references to actual MariaDB (or MySQL) documentation that would clearly state the same thing.

Comment: There is absolutely nothing that prevents  transaction 1 to be committed after transaction 2, in MySQL, MariaDB, or any other SQL database. `commit` is a separate call issued by the client driver, and there is any number of reasons why it might have a longer delay in connection 1.

Comment: This is starting to sound like an actual answer here :) I'd be happy to accept the answer if this would be turned into a real answer. And would wrapping the `INSERT` query in an explicit `START TRANSACTION; ... COMMIT;` be a workaround? I suppose not?

Answer (score 0):

It is unlikely, *but possible*, for "102" to `COMMIT` before "101".